# Backup software for automatic mirroring folders from one drive to another?

Tags: gratis, backup

I am looking for software which will allow me to sync the entire drive (E:) to a folder on another drive (D:). It should be completely free and should copy new files from E: to that folder on D: every 3-6 hours.

Comment: Do you have an operating system preference, or is any acceptable?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard mentioning drive letters probably means Windows (unless it's DOS or OS2/eComStation). **ScarWolf:** Please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) :) And check with [these Google-Search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=rsync+windows) – RSync is (at least on Linux/Unix) the first choice for this kind of task.

Comment: GoodSync, PureSync, FreeFileSync, AllwaySync, SyncBack SE...The list is long, any software on it will match your (very basic) requirements and virtually all of these will have a free version of some kind.

Perhaps you have some other requirements in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using [BitITorrent Sync](https://getsync.com) and am very pleased with it.

It is free, easy to set up and handles more devices than just PCs.

Ufortunately, I am behinfd acompany firewall at the moment, so can't access it's home page to quote form there. This is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_Sync):

> BitTorrent Sync by BitTorrent, Inc is a proprietary peer-to-peer file
>   synchronisation tool available for Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, iOS,
>   Windows Phone, Amazon Kindle Fire and BSD. It can sync files between
>   devices on a local network, or between remote devices over the
>   Internet via a modified version of the BitTorrent protocol.
>
> Although not touted by the developers as an intended direct
>   replacement nor competitor to cloud-based file synchronisation
>   services, it has attained much of its publicity in this potential
>   role.[1](https://getsync.com) This is mainly due to the ability of BitTorrent Sync to
>   address many of the concerns in existing services relating to file
>   storage limits, privacy, cost, and performance.

There is a nice review from PC mag [here](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2464852,00.asp).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[DSynchronize](http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/) is a very useful for this purpose. It works great. I have been using it for some time now. Lots of features. You can download it [here](http://dimio.altervista.org/stats/download.php?id=3)